# Memory not released when a pyqtgraph Plot is closed

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

My Python QApplication has a button (on the main window) which, when clicked, launches a pyqtgraph Plot. The code below shows how the plot is generated within a class.

```
self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
self.win.setWindowTitle(self.title)
self.p = self.win.addPlot()
self.curve = self.p.plot(self.Data1)
```

One of the things I have noticed is that when I close the plot window in my application, the memory is not released. So for example, before the button is pressed, the Application takes around 20Mb. Once the plot is launched by clicking the button, this increases to 25Mb. But when I close the plot (by clicking on the x in the top right corner), the Application memory footprint stays at 25Mb. Is there any way to release this 5Mb of memory when the plot is closed (note that I have the line `self.curve.clear()` so there is no leak while the plot is being updated in real-time).

Is it a case of modifying the `close()` or `closeEvent()` method. Or somehow deleting the reference to the object (though not sure how that would be done).

Many thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. Just closing the window doesn't explicitly deallocate anything. Yes, internally, Window structures aren't used any more, but that doesn't mean it would be wise for the GUI toolkit to throw away everything it has calculated – maybe parts of that would be relevant for the next window, too?
2. Python has a non-deterministic (from a program runtime point of view) Garbage Collection, typical. So there's no guarantee that losing the last reference to an object would instantly free the memory the object uses
3. This might be a misconsception: It's not uncommon for scripting language runtimes to not instantly `free` the memory they have allocated the moment it's not immediately used any more – that would be a terrible strategy, because heuristically, it's pretty likely that you'll need at least parts of that again. And seriously, 5MB of memory (reserved? mapped?) aren't that much on a machine that runs a Python GUI, so there's no benefit of freeing them early. Doing so would probably be criticized as bad runtime design.

Comment: Thanks for this Marcus! I know that 5Mb is not much but it does mount up if e.g. I repeatedly open and close the plot. This suggested to me that perhaps I am not deallocating the object, hence I thought to ask about the proper way to close the plot to avoid memory hold.